# Issue regarding displaying a clicked image on an application through an android device

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is the Home.ts file where the `takephoto()` function is coded, i did import the camera and camera options from ionic-native/camera as shown below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  myphoto: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private camera:Camera) {

  }

  takePhoto(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 70,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
     // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
     this.myphoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
    });
  }

}
```

and this is my **Home.html** file :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
  </p>

  <button ion-button (click)="takePhoto()"> Take Photo </button>

  <p align ="center"><img src="{{ myphoto }}"></p>
</ion-content>
```

Once I click an image on my android device it doesn't show the end result on home.html can anyone please tell what is causing this issue.

I am attaching the screenshots down below:
[this is the image that I took after clicking the take photo button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I250x.jpg)

[As you can see through this image that the final image doesn't show up on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vPrt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prefix the `imageData` with `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'`